# Mongo Bulk Insert across multiple collections

Tags: mongodb, collections, bulkinsert

I see that mongo has [bulk insert](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/), but I see nowhere the capability to do bulk inserts across multiple collections.
Since I do not see it anywhere I'm assuming its not available from Mongo. 
Any specific reason for that?

Answer (score 8):

You are correct in that the bulk API operates on single collections only.

There is no specific reason but the APIs in general are collection-scoped so a "cross-collection bulk insert" would be a design deviation.

You can of course set up multiple bulk API objects in a program, each on a different collection.

#### Update Nov 2019

As of version 4.2 (Aug 2019), all such operations can be performed in a transaction context (startTrans-commit-rollback) if necessary.

Comment: But then these calls would not be transactional right?

Comment: Correct -- but even a bulk insert to a single collection is currently not transactional in the startTrans-commit-rollback sense.

Comment: Update:   As of MongoDB 4.0 (June 2018) bulk inserts can now be transactional even across collections.   As of MongoDB 4.2 (Aug 2019), this extends to collections that are sharded.

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti If possible can you please update your answer with latest possibility of bulk across multiple collection.