# Can BulkWrite operation be used for multiple collections?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I know bulk operations can be done like this:

```
var upsertOne = new UpdateOneModel<BsonDocument>(filter, update) { IsUpsert = true };
bulkOps.Add(upsertOne);
collection.BulkWrite(bulkOps);
```

(source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35688613/8344202)

But is it also possible to update two different collections in one bulk operation?

```
// Entity of CollectionA
bulkOps.Add(new UpdateOneModel<MyClassA>(filter, update) { IsUpsert = true });

// Entity of CollectionB 
bulkOps.Add(new UpdateOneModel<MyClassB>(filter, update) { IsUpsert = true });
collection.BulkWrite(bulkOps);
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: This answers your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/30952307/1390548

Comment: @Jawad yes, exactly what I was looking for. thanks